# How to random sample a 2-parameter weibull distribution in python

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy, weibull

I was wondering how to generate a random weibull distribution with 2-parameter (lambda, k) in python. I know that numpy has a [numpy.random.weibull](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.weibull.html), but it only accepts the *a* parameter as the shape of the distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Severin Pappadeux's answer is probably the simplest way to include the scale parameter.  An alternative is to use [`scipy.stats.weibull_min`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.weibull_min.html).  `weibull_min` has three parameters: shape, location and scale.  You only want the shape and scale, so you would set the location to 0.

```
from scipy.stats import weibull_min

n = 100     # number of samples
k = 2.4     # shape
lam = 5.5   # scale

x = weibull_min.rvs(k, loc=0, scale=lam, size=n)
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, if you sample a number from weibull distribution with scale parameter missing (which assumes scale is equal to 1), then to get it scale multiply by lambda.

```
x = numpy.random.weibull(a)
return lambda*x
```